# converting columns to a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

how to convert a df with several columns to a dictionary? reversing the workflow of this code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df= pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Vikram','John', 'Alex','Paul','Andrew','Rafel' ], 
'Age':[28,39,21,50,35,43], 
'Department':['HR', 'Finance','IT','HR','IT','IT'], 
'Country':['USA','India','Germany','USA','India','India'] })
print(df.head())
```

Comment: `to_dict` is covered in most PANDAS introductions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.to_dict` the reverse of `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
>>> ORIENT = 'dict'
>>> df.to_dict(orient=ORIENT)
{'Name': {0: 'Vikram',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'Alex',
  3: 'Paul',
  4: 'Andrew',
  5: 'Rafel'},
 'Age': {0: 28, 1: 39, 2: 21, 3: 50, 4: 35, 5: 43},
 'Department': {0: 'HR', 1: 'Finance', 2: 'IT', 3: 'HR', 4: 'IT', 5: 'IT'},
 'Country': {0: 'USA',
  1: 'India',
  2: 'Germany',
  3: 'USA',
  4: 'India',
  5: 'India'}}
```

```
>>> ORIENT = 'list'
>>> df.to_dict(orient=ORIENT)
{'Name': ['Vikram', 'John', 'Alex', 'Paul', 'Andrew', 'Rafel'],
 'Age': [28, 39, 21, 50, 35, 43],
 'Department': ['HR', 'Finance', 'IT', 'HR', 'IT', 'IT'],
 'Country': ['USA', 'India', 'Germany', 'USA', 'India', 'India']}
```

and so on... [Read the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)